# Automating MS Access to upload/Export files and merge into a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this code that imports a csv file into an Access table.
There are several problems or ideas that are beyond my level of skills.
The first issue is the file does not append existing fields, instead the entire file is inserted create a duplicate including new headers.

The second issue is I would like to export only new or updated records in a csv file out of Access, not the entire table, I have not gotten there yet.

I need a little hand holding here.

Thank you everyone, this forum and you guys are the best. Always helpful and wailing to share your knowledge.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub ImportFile()
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String

Dim xlApp As Object, xlWb As Object, xlWs As Object
Dim lngRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

strPath = "C:\Transit\"
strTable = "Transit"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTable)

Do While Len(strFile) > 0

      strPathFile = strPath & strFile

        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile)
        Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)

        lngLastRow = xlWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow

            rst.AddNew
            rst("Field1") = xlWs.Range("A" & lngRow).Value
            rst("Field2") = xlWs.Range("B" & lngRow).Value
            rst("Field3") = xlWs.Range("C" & lngRow).Value
            rst("Field4") = xlWs.Range("D" & lngRow).Value
            rst("Field5") = xlWs.Range("E" & lngRow).Value
            rst("Field6") = xlWs.Range("F" & lngRow).Value
            rst("Field7") = xlWs.Range("G" & lngRow).Value
            rst.Update

        Next

    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    Set xlWs = Nothing
    strFile = Dir()
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a linked table to that file. Once you've done that, you can treat the linked Excel file like any other table, including running SELECT and action queries. In your case, you could create a simple Append query with the Excel spreadsheet as its destination, and limit it to only those records which haven't been updated.

[image: Link external Excel file]
It will also be visible in the Query Designer's Add Tables dialog box.

---

**Updated**

If the path to the Excel file is not fixed, you will need a little VBA to automate relinking the file.

```
'Defined as a function instead of a Sub
'Allows calling from an AutoExec macro, or setting as an eventhandler property
Public Function Relink(path As String)
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database, tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim newConnect As String
    Dim connectParts As Variant, part As Variant, keyValuePair As Variant
    Dim key As String, value As String, delimiterPosition As Integer

    'Objects created from CurrentDb can only be referenced once; after that they cause an error
    'Therefore we need save a reference to the Database object in a variable
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'Each table has a corresponding TableDef (table definition) object
    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("LinkedSheet")

    'TableDef objects have a Connect property, containing a connection string for linked tables
    '(For non-linked tables this will be a zero-length string)
    'A connection string has the form key=value;key1=value1 etc.
    connectParts = Split(tdf.Connect, ";")
    For Each part In connectParts
        keyValuePair = Split(part, "=")
        If keyValuePair(0) = "DATABASE" Then
            keyValuePair(1) = path
        End If
        newConnect = newConnect & ";" & Join(keyValuePair, "=")
    Next

    'We need to remove the extra semicolon in the beginning
    newConnect = Mid(newConnect, 2)

    'Set the connection string, and save the change by calling RefreshLink
    tdf.Connect = newConnect
    tdf.RefreshLink
End Function
```

Comment: Good morning, the problem with using a link table is, the Excel/CSV file name changes every time. Linking to it will not work.

Comment: Then focus on automating that. There are a few gotchas, so I will post some code shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful in getting me started.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a bit of a short answer, but with a little looking up, I think it will help.

Look into the **DoCmd.TransferText** command. With that you can import your csv file into a temp table. You even have the option of specifying if the file has headers. It would look something like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "temp", "c:\Transit\myfile.csv", True
```

Once you have it in a temp table, you do a query to see which records are new and append them to your permanent table.